# Update Vue model from jQuery

Tags: jquery, vue.js

This is my Vue code:

```
<div id="root">
    <input v-model="title" name="title" />
    <div class="my-title">{title}</div>
</div>
```

I need to change the input value after a click on a button in jQuery (I can't change this part), something like:

```
$('.button').on('click', function() {
    $("input[name='title']").val('some new value');
});
```

This works as expected, the input value showed in the browser is now `some new value` but the message in `my-title div` is not updated.

Any ideas about how to update it?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? The click event can be handled from vue.

Comment: I simplified my example, actually it's not a click event but an Ajax call to some API and i have to do it using jQuery, i know this is weird and not a best practice

Comment: Impossibile that you "have to do it with jQuery". You are doing it wrong. Add your code so other users can help you to use Vue properly. 

Just to tell you, vue use a virtual dom, that generate the dom. With jQuery you are changing the dom, not the virtual dom. To change the dom, you have to do it within vue..

Comment: Unfortunately this is how it's developed right now not by me, i just needed to make this fix. This totally makes sense anyway, I'll replace the jQuery Ajax call using Vue.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken v-model listens to the input event on that element, so you can try to trigger the input event on the input element with the value you'd like.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default, v-model on text inputs listens to native `input` events in order to synchronise the view-model. You can set the value as you did and then just trigger native `input` event in order to update the value in model.

```js
$('.button').on('click', function() {
  
  // Find inputs
  const input = $("input[name='title']");

  // Set value
  input.val('some new value');

  // Create native event
  const event = new Event('input', { bubbles: true });

  // Dispatch the event on "native" element
  input.get(0).dispatchEvent(event);
});
```

Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/548jofad/

Comment: Thank you so much, you helped me solve a dead end in my thinking!

Answer (score 2):

You could dispatch customEvents to window object, and then listen to those events in Vue component. See the working snippet.

```js
const app = new Vue({
el: "#app",
data: {
  title: "title"
  },
created(){
   window.addEventListener('updateInput', (event) => {
       this.title = event.detail
   });
  }
})

$('.button').on('click', function() {
    window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("updateInput", { detail: 'some new title' } ) );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <input v-model="title" name="title" />
    <div class="my-title">{{title}}</div>
</div>

<button class="button">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a reference to the vue app, you can easily set it.

```
const app = new Vue({ ... });

$(....).click(() => {
  app.title = 'whatever';
})
```